# Get Last Node Access Timestamp Per Node by User

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

Drupal 8.x

I am trying to compare the current users last access timestamp to other timestamp values and am wondering how to get the current users "last_access" in [HOOK_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.5.x).

**MYMODULE.module:**

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  kpr(\Drupal::currentUser()->getLastAccessedTime());
}
```

This returns a timestamp, however, it updates quite infrequently and not on node load, or even after cache clear, and does not seem node specific.

I've accessed this value in HOOK_preprocess_user() with `$variables['elements']['#user']->access->value`, however, I would like the same value available in node.

How do you get the timestamp of the user's last view of a node per node?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because the node is cached. Disabling caching of the node wouldn't be a good idea, performance-wise. Try instead a lazy builder to retrieve the access time and create a placeholder, so that the node can be cached, no matter how often the access time is updated:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node templates.
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['timestamp'] = [
    '#lazy_builder' => ['mymodule_timestamp_current_user', []],
    '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
  ];
}

/**
 * #lazy_builder callback; builds timestamp markup with current user access time.
 */
function mymodule_timestamp_current_user() {
  $timestamp = \Drupal::currentUser()->getLastAccessedTime();
  return [
    '#markup' => $timestamp,
    '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
  ];
}
```

**Drupal ^9**: The callback needs to be in a class implementing TrustedCallbackInterface or RenderCallbackInterface. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/303039/47547 for a code example.

---

**Statistics**

This code extends the code you had so far. If you are referring to statistical node view data have a look at the core Statistics module, which provides a timestamp when the node was last viewed. However, not on a per user basis, but this gives you an idea how you can record such statistical data.

Comment: I am testing this, but it seems to return the same results. The timestamp returned is the same for every node. Note: I am viewing standard nodes, and node teasers view rendered via content in a views block. Any thoughts?

Comment: The first part of the answer is about the caching aspect how to include a timestamp in a node in general. For the second part, since core doesn't record view access timestamps for nodes by default you need to do this before you can display such information.

Comment: I think I am missing something... It seems like `\Drupal::currentUser()->getLastAccessedTime()` in `mymodule_timestamp_current_user()` returns the same value that `\Drupal::currentUser()->getLastAccessedTime()` in  `mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables)` does. The same timestamp value for every node. I think I understand what is written above, create a variable per user with no cache, and then call it in preprocess_node(), but it looks like when `\Drupal::currentUser()->getLastAccessedTime()` is called in preprocess_node() it gets rendered as if built in that function.

Comment: @Prestosaurus — To me it seems that `getLastAccessedTime` returns just the time when the current user logged in **to your site** for the last time. Under no circumstances this method seems to get connected to a/the node, no?

Comment: @leymannx that appears correct. There is no association to 'node'. Ready for alternative ideas... hidden form, custom SQL...?

Answer (score 1):

[`User::getLastAccessedTime`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Entity!User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetLastAccessedTime/8.2.x) will only give you

> The timestamp when the account last accessed the site.

Under no circumstances this value is going to be associated to a node.

---

So what I'd do now is the following:

1. Add a new field to the user that's going to be used to store the data we need. Maybe a JSON field ([module A](https://www.drupal.org/project/json_field) or [module B](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonb), I don't know which one is better) or any other custom field that is capable of holding an array of nodes and timestamps. Hide that field from display.
2. Add a new pseudo/extra field to your node type that will get and display the last accessed time for the current node, and then will set a new timestamp. Which maybe could look like this (untested!):

---

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;

function MYMODULE_entity_extra_field_info() {

  $extra = [];

  foreach (NodeType::loadMultiple() as $bundle) {

    $extra['node'][$bundle->id()]['display']['last_accessed'] = [
      'label'       => t('Node Last Accessed'),
      'description' => t('Displays the timestamp the current node got last accessed by the current user'),
      'visible'     => FALSE, // Initially set to hidden on Display Settings.
    ];
  }

  return $extra;
}

function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  $current_uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $current_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($current_uid);

  $current_nid = $entity->id();

  // Now you have the current user entity and the current node ID.

  // Now you need to get the value of the custom field which probably should
  // be an associated array of node IDs and timestamps.
  $access_data = $current_user->get('field_node_access_data')->getValue();

  // Now you need to look up if the current node ID already is in it and if so, 
  // retrieve its timestamp value.
  $timestamp = ... // your job.

  if ($display->getComponent('last_accessed')) {

    $build['last_accessed'] = [
      '#markup' => $timestamp,
      // I hope this works that way. That the cache gets disabled properly for
      // just this pseudo field.
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
    ];
  }

  // And now finally after the timestamp has been rendered it needs to get updated.
  $current_user->set('field_node_access_data')->... // Your job. Probably something with time().
  $current_user->save();
}
```

---

Again, this is absolutely untested. And if the cache busting for the markup in the pseudo field display doesn't work I'd probably try the same approach with a custom block. Or the lazy builder approach as highlighted in the other answer. But a block can easily be excluded from cache and you can use a theme, contexts and what else a little bit easier maybe than what you have in a preprocess hook.

Comment: I have been testing with a `HOOK_install()`, `HOOK_shema()` type approach. Writing directly to the DB. I really like the approach above. A field that could be placed on a node would be very flexible... I will take some time to test this out

Comment: @Prestosaurus – You may have seen I did a pretty similar thing now in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/273986/15055. Just that there the pseudo field is placed on the user.

Comment: @Prestosaurus – For your problem I would recommend to add a real field to the user or user table via hook_install. This field will never be exposed anywhere. It's just there to store the data (custom table actually would be fine as well). And then you place a pseudo field on the node and ajaxify its content similar to what I've done in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working with database tables I have come up with this option so far:

**MYMODULE.module:**

```
/**
 * This creates a database to store the last access timestamp per node per user.
 */

/**
 * implements HOOK_preprocess_node().
 */
function node_access_timestamp_by_user_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // Set current user ID.
  $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

  // Check if user is authenticated.
  if ($uid != 0) {

    // Get current NID, Timestamp, and DB.
    $currentNID = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
    $currentTimestamp = intval(time());
    $database = \Drupal::database();

    // Query our DB.
    $queryDBEntries = $database
      ->select('node_access_timestamp_by_user', 'timestamp')
      ->fields('timestamp')
      ->condition('uid', $uid, "=")
      ->condition('nid', $currentNID, "=");

    // Fetch DB data.
    $result = $queryDBEntries->execute()->fetchAll();

    // Check if table row exists and overwrite.
    if ($result[0]->uid == $uid && $result[0]->nid == $currentNID) {
      $database
        ->update('node_access_timestamp_by_user')
        ->fields([
          'timestamp' => $currentTimestamp,
        ])
        ->condition('uid', $uid, '=')
        ->condition('nid', $currentNID, '=')
        ->execute();
    }

    // Check if table row does not exist and create.
    if ($result[0]->uid != $uid && $result[0]->nid != $currentNID) {
      $database
        ->insert('node_access_timestamp_by_user')
        ->fields([
          'uid' => $uid,
          'nid' => $currentNID,
          'timestamp' => $currentTimestamp,
        ])
        ->execute();
    }

    // Set our $variables to print in twig.
    if ($result[0]->nid == $currentNID) {
      $variables['nodeAccessTimestampByUser_uid'] = $result[0]->uid;
      $variables['nodeAccessTimestampByUser_nid'] = $result[0]->nid;
      $variables['nodeAccessTimestampByUser_timestamp'] = $result[0]->timestamp;
    }

  }

}

/**
* Implements HOOK_install().
*
* Creates some default entries on this module custom table.
*
* @see hook_install()
*
* @ingroup node_access_timestamp_by_user
*/
function node_access_timestamp_by_user_install() {

  $currentTimestamp = intval(time());
  $database = \Drupal::database();

  // Add a default entry.
  $fields = [
    'uid' => '1',
    'nid' => '1',
    'timestamp' => $currentTimestamp,
  ];
  $database
    ->insert('node_access_timestamp_by_user')
    ->fields($fields)
    ->execute();
}

/**
* Implements HOOK_schema().
*
* Defines the database tables used by this module.
*
* @see hook_schema()
*
* @ingroup node_access_timestamp_by_user
*/
function node_access_timestamp_by_user_schema() {

  $currentTimestamp = intval(time());

  $schema['node_access_timestamp_by_user'] = [
    'description' => 'Stores node access timestamp by user per node.',
    'fields' => [
      'uid' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 1,
        'description' => "User's {users}.uid",
    ],
      'nid' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 1,
        'description' => "Node ID",
    ],
      'timestamp' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => $currentTimestamp,
        'description' => "Timestamp",
    ],
    ],
    'primary key' => ['nid'],
    'indexes' => [
      'uid' => ['uid'],
      'nid' => ['nid'],
      'timestamp' => ['timestamp'],
    ],
  ];

  return $schema;
}
```

**node.html.twig:**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>UID</td>
          <td>{{ nodeAccessTimestampByUser_uid }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NID</td>
        <td>{{ nodeAccessTimestampByUser_nid }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Timestamp</td>
        <td>{{ nodeAccessTimestampByUser_timestamp }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is only moderately tested, and I would not be someone who could talk about performance impacts.

I am overwriting tables fields instead of adding to... I feel that if you stored every instance like a `history`, the database would get gigantic.

Comment: Hmmm, I think this is going to be cached too hard, as @4k4 explicitly highlighted in their answer. Did you test this already with all caches enabled?

Comment: I have been testing that today, cache does seem an obstacle. Unfortunate, I liked the data in the DB, but even a custom view is getting cached data. You're welcome to take a look: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access_timestamp_by_user. I am going to try your answer next but will need some time, I have little experience with a couple of the aspects involved.

Comment: I'll have a look. It's very important information that this is for a contrib module. Certain things may need to be considered more thoroughly then.

Comment: I am happy to see this through, would like to see a solution.